# exact same shiny code can insert image in shiny but in shiny flexdashboard the image failed to show up

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I run the exact same code in both `shiny` and `shiny flexdashboard`. The image can be inserted using `shiny` but failed for `shiny flexdashboard`. The image is stored in www folder and put in the same directory with the code file.

Does anyone know what the reason behind this would be?

**shiny code:**

```
  setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/Shiny dashboard")
  b=read.csv("table_clusterupdate.csv")

  shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
   img(src="cluster.png", height = 500, width = 900),
   fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))
   ),
   server = function(input, output) {output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
   b, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
   )
   })
```

**Shiny flexdashboard code:**

````
 ---
title: "R"
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/Shiny dashboard")
b=read.csv("table_clusterupdate.csv")

```
Multidimensional OP cluster 
===========================================
```{r}
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(

img(src="cluster.png", height = 500, width = 900),
fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))
 ),
server = function(input, output) {output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
b, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
 )
 })
```
````

Comment: have you tried to remove setwd() lines?

Comment: yes ,  the image still cannot be inserted to the flexdashboard. I suspect maybe it is due to  rmd file so somehow the way to insert the image is different from pure shinyapp ?